# Laravel Homstead vagrant SSH not working correctly

Tags: vagrant, git-bash, homestead

I installed Homestead following the instractions on:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead

I can start the vagrant box with: vagrant up.

But when i want to vagrant ssh into my box it starts to get strange

It gets stuck here:

[image]

not showing the directory where i am in.

I am using Git bash on windows. Everything is up to date VM, Vagrant fresch installation.

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: What happens if you press `Ctrl+C`, while in the state depicted in the screenshot? Are you "dropped" onto the next line in the terminal? Also, it would be helpful to know *exactly* which versions of Git Bash, VirtualBox, and Vagrant you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue a few days ago myself. The problem seems to be happening with GitBash only. When using PowerShell or another terminal to run "vagrant ssh" it works. To work with GitBash you will need to use ConEmu and create a new GitBash tab.

Answer (score 1):

We discovered this was a bug with Vagrant 2.0.1, Downgrading to 2.0.0 on Windows resolves it. Or using another terminal editor. Seems to be caused by Git Bash + Vagrant 2.0.1.

https://github.com/laravel/homestead/issues/723

Answer (score 0):

Add VAGRANT_PREFER_SYSTEM_BIN=1 before vagrant will solve this problem.

```
VAGRANT_PREFER_SYSTEM_BIN=1 vagrant ssh
```

If you feel it's too much hassle to do this every time,
adding it to Windows' System Variables is a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

I met with the same issue and didn't know how to fix it.
You can use

`ssh vagrant@ip-address`

instead. Use you IP address in place of ip-address.